# How can i debug xamarin Android with emulator

Tags: xamarin.android

I make a android app by xamarin.

I could deploy and move app in emulator successfully.

And next, I want to debug source.

So add break point to source then click debug after clean project.

As a result, project built but deploying skipped and over. happened nothing.

I unchecked "use Fast Deployment(only debug mode)"

And "Preserve application data cache on device between deploys" is uncheck too.
(tried checking and unchecking)

Can i get some idea? Thank you.

Comment: It could probably be a design mistake on the Xaml side. The compiler can not catch this error when it is run, but it can be a mistake that prevents it from being installed during the installation.

If you use SQLite as an Extra, sometimes you may experience a similar situation in database changes. This problem can be solved by removing the old application and re-deploying it.

Comment: Mahmut Bedir // Thank you for your comment! But It just didn't set to deploy project. I opened conifiguration manager and check to deploy. And now, It is built and deployed successfully when i click debug. Thank you.